# How to call a dynamically named function in Railo

Tags: railo

Suppose I have this struct:

```
myValue = {
      value = 100,
      formatter = "numberFormat",
      formatMask = "0.0"
};
```

How can I call up the function specified in myValue.formatter?  Such as this:

```
var valueString = myValue[ "formatter" ]( myValue.value, myValue.formatMask );
```

The write-ups on dynamically-named function tend to focus on component methods or custom defined functions, such as [this](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/09/functions-and-their-execution-context.html).  However, it doesn't seem to work with native functions.  I am running Railo 4.2 btw.

Is there a way to dynamically call native functions? Or do I have to fall back to doing if/then statements (if "numberFormat" then return numberFormat(val,mask)) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`numberFormat()` is a built-in function, and CFML built-in functions are not "first class" so cannot be called like that: one cannot make a reference to a built-in function, which is necessary for this sort of thing to work.

You'll need to revise your approach here, possibly using `evaluate()`, or wrapping `numberFormat()` in your own UDF.